# When did Dei gratia/fidi defensor first appear on British coins?

Tags: numismatics, great-britain

Just as the title says: When did Dei gratia (D.G.) /fidi (fidei) defensor (F.D.) first appear on British coins?

Answering [When and how did the British Monarchy stop claiming Divine Right](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/12926/when-and-how-did-the-british-monarchy-stop-claiming-divine-right) made me realize that I don't know when this first appeared.

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defender_of_the_Faith answer your question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On [British coinage](https://collections.museumsvictoria.com.au/items/53725):

> The title Fidei Defensor abbreviated to F.D. (Defender of the Faith)
> occurs for the first time on the British coinage under George I.

The earliest example is from the very beginning of his reign, in 1714.

[image]

*"1 Guinea - George I 1st portrait". Source: [Numista](https://en.numista.com/catalogue/pieces27964.html)*

The inscription appears frequently on coins from here on. For example, a 1722 silver shilling reads (obverse):

> GEORGIVS D G M BR FR ET HIB REX F D (translation: George I by the
> Grace of God King of Great Britain, France and Ireland, Defender of
> the Faith).

[image]

*Image source: [1722 Great Britain Silver Shilling Coin George I, ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/1722-Great-Britain-Silver-Shilling-Coin-George-I-ANACS-VF-30-Details-Cleaned-/182490799571)*

However, not all coins during his reign bore this inscription: see [this 1722 farthing](https://en.numista.com/catalogue/pieces13087.html), for example.

The terms "dei gratia" or "gratia dei" (followed by "rex") on coins can be dated back much earlier, to [Anglo-Saxon times](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=KF4VAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA140-IA6&lpg=PA140-IA6&dq=dei%20gratia%20fidei%20defensor%20origin&source=bl&ots=bR0zViq9HQ&sig=ACfU3U35VnEGGqf5PQaHMtixmgeBKoI28Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHwsv8_8zwAhUqyosBHQu-DvsQ6AEwEHoECAUQAw#v=onepage&q=dei%20gratia&f=false). For example, it was used by [Coenwulf of Mercia](http://Coenwulf%20of%20Mercia) (reigned 796 to 821). It was also used by the Normans and their successors, though not on all coins.

---

***Note***

A paragraph in the Wikipedia page for [King James VI & I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_VI_and_I#cite_note-FOOTNOTEWillson1963252%E2%80%93253-209) is somewhat poorly phrased in that it implies James used *Defender of the Faith* on coins. However, the sources cited [(Willson 1967](https://archive.org/details/kingjamesvii00will/page/n7/mode/2up?q=coinage) and [Croft 2003](https://archive.org/details/kingjames00crof)) do not say that; rather, they are referring to the use of the title *King of Great Brittaine* (which was controversial). Nor can I find any James VI or I coins with *D.F.*.

Comment: Lolx! I actually used to own such a 1772 farthing :-)